# Why doesn't this add markers to my Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, frontend, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have this leaflet map inside a HTML file that I can easily return with my Flask app.py, but I've been trying to add a marker for a while now to no avail.

```
var marker = L.marker([latitud, longitud]);
var addmarker = L.addmarker([marker]).addTo(map_init);
```

The marker stuff is at the bottom, but I'm sharing the whole file in case I messed up somewhere else

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>mapa pelao</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-control-geocoder@1.16.0/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100vh - 20px);
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div id="map" class="mapa-img"></div>
        <script src=""LINK HERE"
            integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="></script>
        <script src="LINK HERE"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                // se crea el mapa
                var map_init = L.map('map', {
                    center: [-33.4449, -70.6664],
                    zoom: 13
                });

                // se usa OpenStreetMap para agregar la imagen al mapa creado
                var osm = L.tileLayer("LINK HERE", {
                    attribution: "&copy; <a href='"LINK HERE'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                }).addTo(map_init);

                // se agrega un buscador para el mapa
                L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map_init);

                // Obtener la posición desde la base de datos (ejemplo)
                var latitud = -33.4450;
                var longitud = -70.6694;

                // Crear un marcador en la posición obtenida
                var marker = L.marker([latitud, longitud]);
                var addmarker = L.addmarker([marker]).addTo(map_init);
            });

        </script>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

AFAIK it should show the marker with just that, I've been messing with it but nothing changes, I can even change the center of the map, so atleast not the whole file is messed up.
Example of a change that didn't work:

```
var addmarker = L.addmarker([latitud, longitud]).addTo(map_init);
```

And yes, eventually I'd want to pull positions from a database, but first I need to know how to even place a single marker.

Comment: Because you make the marker with `L.marker([lat, long])` and then you add that to the map by either chaining `.addTo(map)` or by saving the marker in a variable and calling `.addto(map)` on that. This is very much covered by [the quick start guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start) so give that a (re)read and use the code that tells you to use. With the added bonus that Leaflet's on v1.9.4 now, not v1.7.1

Comment: `L.addmarker()` is not a thing in the Leaflet JS API.

Comment: Damm I really thought `L.marker()` was just the Lplus  the variable name... thank you both for answering.